# Xml Framing for akka streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm consuming stream of `ByteString`s from TCP endpoint using akka streams. Chunks of data should form one or many XML documents. I'd like my stream to output `ByteString`s with full Xmls.

For example such source

```
Source(List(
  "<Update1></Update1><Update2></Update2>", 
  "<Update3>", 
  "</Update3>"
))
```

attached to this stream should materialize:

```
List(
  "<Update1></Update1>", 
  "<Update2></Update2>", 
  "<Update3></Update3>"
)
```

(For simplicity I'm now wrapping strings as ByteString).

Comment: Have you tried https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/data-transformations/xml.html ?  The `XmlParsing.subtree` flow in particular looks like it's very close (specifically if it handles an empty path specification).